# linux mint 17 fails to login to desktop

Tags: linux, xorg

forgive the noobie question...

my desktop fails to start, just hangs there with a mobile mouse cursor.
when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to cli, login, try `startx`

I get Xkeyboard keymap errors; then the connection to X server refused with...
xinit: unexpected signal 2

It hints that this could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard.config

please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your .Xauthority file:
To do this: 
Type in terminal

```
sudo rm /home/{USER}/.Xauthority
```

After that you should restart your system (with your normal user account).

**If it would't work, try to login with root account**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response,  it didn't work, no such file exists... Apparently.

Comment: Although I'm now getting /etc/mum/Xsession: Beginning session setup...

Comment: localuser:{username} being added to access control list....    Script for none started at run_im.... Script for auto started at run_im..... Script for default started at run_im..

Comment: mkdtemp:private socket directory: Permission denied

Comment: Second comment should read... /etc/mdm/Xsession

Comment: Tried with root, can't seem to locate. Xauthority

Comment: I cd to /etc/pam.d      then   ls....no sign of xserver file

Comment: Do you have file that called "mdm" ?

Comment: Yes I got mdm directory in etc, and in etc/pam.d I got mdm file and mdm-autologin

Comment: change mdm file like I gave you below

Comment: I tried it last night without success.

Comment: Before changing it I get to login page. Enter details then press enter, screen goes black....as it usually does, but instead of the few seconds before the cinnamon desktop appears, it just hangs there - black with a mouse pointer.

Comment: When I tried your change I got an error popup just before the login page...

Comment: I could try again...but would like to know about the rest of the file contents, do I erase all? Or fit in your change at the appropriate spot, erasing just a line or two? Or do I add it and leave the rest unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Then try to fix this by editing /etc/pam.d/mdm file. It should look like this::

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth sufficient pam_rootok.so
#auth required pam_console.so
auth sufficient pam_permit.so
account sufficient pam_permit.so
session optional pam_keyinit.so force revoke
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Before editing this file make sure you have a backup. Then edit that file. Here is my mdm file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
    auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
    auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
    @include common-auth
    auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
    auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
    @include common-account
    session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
    session required        pam_limits.so
    @include common-session
    session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
    session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
    session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
    session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
    session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
    @include common-password
```

Comment: My mdm differs by 2 lines, those regarding kwallet.  So how do I action your earlier edit? Delete all else? Integrate? Or append?

Comment: I've edited boot file to now boot to cli...but if I startx then I get the same error.... Loading extension Glx.        The Xkeyboard keypad compiler (xkbcomp) reports:  Error:  cannot open "temp/filedjfeet" to write keyboard description.      Exiting.                           [then also]     cannot open "/temp/fileqecden" to write the keyboard description.   Exiting.          xkbcomp failed to compile keymap. "

Comment: -1
down vote
accept

Thanks for your help, but I've decided to use the quick bludgeon rather than the slow scalpel. Backed up my files and fresh installed. Sorted. Thanks again for trying